# How to compile a procedure including if & elsif statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Good day,

I am trying to create the below procedure that will update a table (annouce_form) based on a job category, plus I would like to know if it is possible to include multiple update commands in one procedure:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_ANNOUCMENT_FORM (   
    p_annoucment_id IN annouce_form.ANNOUCMENT_ID%TYPE,  
    p_current_doc   IN annouce_form.CURRENT_DOC%TYPE,
    p_current_other IN annouce_form.current_other%TYPE,
    p_job_category  IN REGISTRATION_FORM.JOB_CATEGORY%TYPE
    )  
    IS  
    BEGIN  

 --first update
   IF p_job_category = 'Medical' THEN
   UPDATE annouce_form
   SET CURRENT_DOC = p_current_doc + 1 
   WHERE ANNOUCMENT_ID = p_annoucment_id;
   ELSIF p_job_category != 'Medical' THEN 
   SET CURRENT_OTHER = p_current_other + 1
   WHERE ANNOUCMENT_ID = p_annoucment_id;
   end if; 

 --second update
   UPDATE annouce_form
   SET CURRENT_OTHER = p_current_other + 1
   WHERE ANNOUCMENT_ID = p_annoucment_id;

   COMMIT;
   END;
```

and I receive the below error after compiling it in SQL developer tool:

```
    Procedure UPDATE_ANNOUCMENT_FORM compiled

    LINE/COL  ERROR
    --------- -------------------------------------------------------------
    19/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
    19/5      PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
    20/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHERE" when expecting one of the following:     
    ( begin case declare else elsif end exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return 
    select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a 
    bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback 
    savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge 
    Errors: check compiler log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is wrong:

```
--first update
IF p_job_category = 'Medical' THEN
   UPDATE annouce_form
   SET CURRENT_DOC = p_current_doc + 1 ;
ELSIF p_job_category != 'Medical' THEN 
   SET CURRENT_OTHER = p_current_other + 1;       --> this is 
   WHERE ANNOUCMENT_ID = p_annoucment_id;         --> wrong
end if;
```

I presume it should've been

```
IF p_job_category = 'Medical'
THEN
  UPDATE annouce_form
     SET CURRENT_DOC = p_current_doc + 1;
ELSIF p_job_category != 'Medical'
THEN
  UPDATE annouce_form                               --> probably like this
     SET CURRENT_OTHER = p_current_other + 1
   WHERE ANNOUCMENT_ID = p_annoucment_id;
END IF;
```

but you should know better.

Comment: You're welcome. I meant to say that I tried to guess what you wanted to do (i.e. to update ANNOUNCE_FORM table). Maybe you wanted to do something else; update some other table, or ... can't tell. That's why I said that you should know it. Oh, by the way - the 1st UPDATE statement doesn't have WHERE clause. Beware! You'll update **all rows** in the table! That's probably not what you meant to do.

Comment: thank u for continuous support, about the first update I have "WHERE ANNOUCMENT_ID = p_annoucment_id;" as a where clause, am I missing something? thnx again =)

Comment: Well, no - you don't have it (at least, I don't see it in the question you posted). If you fixed it in the meantime, even better.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad if you made it work.

Answer (score 0):

IF statement blocks must include entire UPDATE statement

```
...
IF p_job_category = 'Medical' THEN
   UPDATE annouce_form
   SET CURRENT_DOC = p_current_doc + 1 
   WHERE ANNOUCMENT_ID = p_annoucment_id;
ELSIF p_job_category != 'Medical' THEN 
   UPDATE annouce_form
   SET CURRENT_OTHER = p_current_other + 1
   WHERE ANNOUCMENT_ID = p_annoucment_id;
 end if;
 ...
```

Alternatively using CASE

```
   UPDATE annouce_form
   SET CURRENT_DOC = case when p_job_category = 'Medical' tnen p_current_other + 1 else CURRENT_DOC end,
       CURRENT_OTHER = case when p_job_category != 'Medical' tnen p_current_other + 1 else CURRENT_OTHER end
   WHERE ANNOUCMENT_ID = p_annoucment_id;
```